# Will magnetic field change velocity

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

As I have studied that magnetic field is not able to change speed of particle but in cyclotron how it can able to increase the speed

Comment: In a cyclotron there is also an electric field present that does work on the particle.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't - the B field is for containment. A charge difference between the two D's accelerates the particles.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron#Principle_of_operation